# How to set SIKULI_HOME env variable after jar packaging?

Tags: java, executable-jar, sikuli

Until now I have tested my Java application for automation developed using Sikuli through Eclipse by setting the `PATH` and `SIKULI_HOME` env variables in the launch configuration itself. Now I am trying to deploy the application using jars.

For this, I have created a batch file which will contain the SET commands for these two variables--

```
SET PATH=C:\JDK64\1.6.0.31.1\bin;C:\Sikuli-IDE-1.0.0-Win64\libs;
SET SIKULI_HOME=C:\Sikuli-IDE-1.0.0-Win64
java -jar myjar.jar
```

However, this doesn't work and results in an infamous issue:

```
[error] org.sikuli.script.FileManager.loadLibrary: Native library could not be loaded: VisionProxy
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Sikuli-IDE-1.0.0-Win64\libs\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Can anyone help me to identify the right solution to set these variables before executing the jars?

Thank you,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about sikuli, but you probably want to *add* Java and Sikuli to the path, and not *replace* the path with just these directories:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\JDK64\1.6.0.31.1\bin;C:\Sikuli-IDE-1.0.0-Win64\libs
```